# Cakephp localhost error - This site can't be reached

Tags: cakephp, localhost, wamp

I have windows 10 and wamp installed. I installed a cakephp copy using composer. It is www folder of wamp.

I am able to see localhost page.

But when I click on the project folder icon,  I get the error: **This site can't be reached**.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

If your "My Project" folder exists in "wamp/www/" and if you can see the localhost home page after starting wampserever correctly, and still you cant access your projects, then simply go to www folder, open index.php and search for $suppress_localhost and set its value to false. Restart wampserver, go to localhost and try to access your project.